# 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: reactjs, windows, react-native, command-prompt

> Creating a new React app in E:\rn-starter\my-app.
>
> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. Installing
> react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
>
> 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.
>
> Aborting installation.   npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel
> error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.
>
> Deleting generated file... package.json Deleting my-app/ from
> E:\rn-starter Done.

This error pops-up whenever I try to create a new react project or react native project. tried re-installing node and

Comment: have you checked this one : https://stackoverflow.com/q/40546231/5669120 ?

Comment: That does not solve my problem

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I was using windows command prompt to do this. Using the git bash resolved the problem for me.
The issue I think was with sh - shell files not being recognized by default in windows.
However with git bash, since it by default recognizes the shell scripts it did work perfectly.

Comment: Good answer but it is not perfect :\

Comment: @Balive13 this may not be the perfect answer. this is just the solution I found to be working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the terminal of the IDE you are using instead of the windows cli...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using the git bash works, but you could also add git (bin folder) to your Path environment variable if you want to run shell scripts in windows terminal.

Default installation path for git is: `C:\Program Files\Git`

[image]
[image]