# "The term 'sh' is not recognized" when installing Rust

Tags: windows, rust

```
sh : The term 'sh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:61
+ curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
+                                                             ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sh:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: You're running on Windows. `sh` is a unix command. The instructions on the page from where you copied that command instructs you [how to install rustup on Windows](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html).

Comment: Related (I don't want to mark as duplicate): ['sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64972826/sh-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: When you go to https://rustup.rs/ on Windows, it says to download and run rustup-init.exe The command line below that is only when using Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: The question is missing a description. There is only an error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.